# Device Installation Settings disable windows update

Tags: c#, driver, windows-update

I need a way to programmatically in C# using form to open the Device Installation Settings window or just auto select "Never install driver software from windows update".

I'm plugging in  multi devices for the first time but drivers are installed and windows want to check every time for a new driver.

(In my form i want to enable on open and disable on form close or just open the window to have the user select.)

Comment: Did you write the drivers?

Comment: No they are phone drivers.

Comment: Then what ... Why do you think that's a good idea?  Do you really think a Windows User is going to want you monkeying around with their Windows settings?  There's a good chance that Windows won't even allow that.

Comment: It is something that can be done manually "Device and Printers + select pc then select device installation settings then select never install driver software from window update. I'm just just trying to make it simple to do for someone else on windows 8.

Comment: If there's a simple way to programmatically type "Change device installation settings" in the search bar to load the window that would be easy also.